# Routing correctly mesh + gatewaty

Tags: routing, router

I have a router modem DSL
I have 2 Aimesh Asus AX XT8

For a reason the node can not talk with the router base over WIFI (long range).
I than connected the lan on the modem(DSL ROUTER) to the NODE - which is on different subnet.
It is working but get many disconnection issues.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].